# Excel Export in ASP.NET Web Service

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I have this ASP.Net Web Application and in one of my Pages I'm using JQuery JQGrid, I want to be able to export the JQGrid to Excel Sheet, so using JavaScript I Collected the Values in an Array and then called a WebService to fill the values in a DataGrid, I successfully done all that, except for the exporting in the WebService no file download appears, and this is my WebService code:

```
[WebMethod]
public void GetData(object[] Values)
{
    DT_ToFill.Columns.Add("CaseID");
    DT_ToFill.Columns.Add("SR");

    foreach (object Value in Values)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> DictVals = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        DictVals = (Dictionary<string, object>)Value;
        string CaseID = DictVals["CaseID"].ToString();
        string SR = DictVals["SR"].ToString();

        object[] Obj = new object[2] { CaseID, SR };
        DT_ToFill.Rows.Add(Obj);
    }
    ExportToExcel(DT_ToFill, Context.Response);
}

[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello World";
}

public void ExportToExcel(DataTable dt, HttpResponse Response)
{
    GridView GridView1 = new GridView();
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=Schedule_ExcelSheet.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter ht = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.RenderControl(ht);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}

public void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
}
```

Help Please...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are sending the excel file back as the response to the ajax request? If so, I don't think you can make a file download work through ajax.

Maybe send the data via ajax like you are doing now, but then do either a new window or an iframe (append it to document.body) and set the src to be a url that returns the excel file. That should trigger the file download. This is what I usually do.

Comment: Yes, your're right @jForrest, but I couldn't understand the second part, how do I do that...?!

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I will try to clarify.

Comment: The file download will work if you either open a new window or by appending an iframe to the page. Easiest might be a new window. So: 1) do what you are doing now to send the data to the server 2) open a new window. Point the new window to a url that will send the xls like you are doing now (maybe use the users session to send the right pdf back?) 3) When the new window loads, it will download the xls